# Rest Sharp returning unable to connect to remote server after 20 mins

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, restsharp

I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to make calls to another API.
When i make the first call to an API it returns expected data within 50-100 milliseconds without any issue but after 20 -30 minute when i made the same request again to the same API end point it returns an error and its taking more than 20000ms to return the error.

Error is "Unable to connect to remote server"

Both the above request are made inside another web application who is consuming those data.

Initially i though there is something wrong on the API but when i tried the same scenario on the postman and it works well.

another important thing is this issue is not happening on debug mode. so i created lots of traces to debug this with the time.

please see the below simple version of the code.

```
readonly IRestClient _client;

public BankClient(IBankSettings settings)
    {
        _client = new RestClient();
     }

public bool IsLicenseKeyValid(string licenseKey)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("URL", Method.GET);

        request.AddHeader(_settings.UserName, licenseKey);
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        var response = _client.Execute<List<BankBuildingPartsModel>>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("BankClient error retrieving response. Check inner details for more info.", response.ErrorException);
        }
        return response.Data != null;
    }
```

Expert help is much appreciated.

Comment: You say you put some traces in. Were you able to determine where the hold up is? Does it definitely get as far as the _Client.Execute on that second request? At what point in time does the REST endpoint log the second GET being made?

Comment: Yes, _Client.Execute is the place where i track the time. so all the time i mention above is the time to pass throgh the _Client.Execute.

Comment: And you see the request in the logs on the REST API you are calling at that point?

Comment: Yes. i see the request.

Comment: How many concurrent requests (i.e. at the same time) do you make to the API?

Comment: That API is not in our hand. i assume there cant be too many requests. my concern is why its working on postman then.?

Comment: Only had Postman work when another way didn't vs. browser and it was CORS but can't be the cause of an intermittent problem.

Comment: Perhaps try HttpClient instead? I prefer it but at least good to narrow problem down.